# Is there still a place for plain enums?

Tags: c++, enums

I have started using strongly typed enums.  Looking through my current project there are a few places were I still prefer plain enums.

If the strongly typed characteristic is unneeded and the enum is being used for its implicit conversion to int, are there any other tradeoffs that would make conventional enums a bad choice?

Comment: Yes, I think so. This question is opinion based; voting to close.

Comment: @ utnapistim It's clearly a good practice( benefits vs drawbacks ) type of question.  Although it could be worded a little better.  He's asking if he has correctly assessed the trade-offs.

Comment: "are there any other tradeoffs" makes this an objective, answerable question that should not have been closed as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: It seems like this might be a good fit for the Programmer Stack Exchange site.